# Delete image files from internal storage and arraylist

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Basically, I'm saving images in internal storage's directory. Then I'm showing them in recyclerview using ArrayList. There is a cross button over each image in row layout(see screenshot). I need to delete the image as per its position not only from recyclerview but also from internal directory. I was able to remove the image from recyclerview's arraylist but the image in the directory does not gets deleted.

```css
// Method in activity to show images from int. storage to recyclerview.

private void showImages(){

        File directory = new File(file_path);
        File newfile[] = directory.listFiles();

        Log.e("sammy_arrlistsize_befor"," "+finalImages.size());

        if(finalImages!=null )finalImages.clear();

        for (int i= 0; i < newfile.length; i++) {
            String path = "file://"+newfile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            finalImages.add(path);
            Log.e("sammy_imagepath"," "+path);
        }

        Log.e("sammy_arrlistsize_after"," "+finalImages.size());

        recyladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

```html
//Adapter

public class RecycleImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> itemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.imagelayout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(itemList.get(position));
            holder.setImageView(uri);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ImageView image, delbtn;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            delbtn = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.del);
            delbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setImageView(Uri uri){
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(uri).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Log.e("sammy_error"," "+errorDrawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//Here I'm deleting image
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, itemList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            File file = new File(itemList.get(position));
            file.delete();

            itemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemList.size());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please check my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired result by only using the absolute path of the image i.e. `newfile[i].getAbsolutePath()` so that the path would be like this `/storage/emulated/0/SAM/IMG_1110.jpg`.

Comment: Did it reflect in your gallery? I am getting true from file.delete() but it is not reflecting in my gallery

Comment: @Maverick7 Use MediaScanner for refreshing after you delete or add file.

Answer (score 1):

In your on click mehod:

Take file path

```
String path = "file://"+newfile[i].getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path);
file.delete();
```

Try this code.

Comment: I'm already getting the path like this: `file///storage/emulated/0/SAM/IMG_1110.jpg` from the present code.

Comment: @CodeAssasins then send this path inside new File(path); and try to delete

Answer (score 0):

```
final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

/*get a path in list file */
final File file = new File(listFile[position].getAbsolutePath());

file.delete();
```

Comment: This does not seem to add anything that the other answers do not have. Perhaps some explanation of why this is different and better would help to make this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mList.get(position).getPath()));
    File fdelete = new File(uri.getPath());
            if (fdelete.exists()) {
                if (fdelete.delete()) {
                    Log.d("filedel","file Deleted :" + uri.getPath());
                } else {
                    Log.d("filedel","file  not Deleted :" + uri.getPath());
                }
            }
```